# Problem with adding mesh

Tags: mesh

whenever i add a mesh on another object, 
the object is always linked : 
when i add a cylinder on a cube and whenever i scale or transform the cylinder also the cube will scale or move, but just in the current project, maybe i changed somethings but i dont know what.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Means by which this could happen:

Object added in 'edit' mode then scale/move/rotate in 'object' mode

Is the object 'parented' to it?

Constraints or drivers can also affect loc/rot/scale.

Comment: They are not parented just new objects ,yes i applied  parent and constraints on previus objects but now seems affecting new too

Comment: Solved ! i had activated the proportional editing